# bundling failed: Error: require() must have a single string literal argument

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native v0.49 and I want to use the props between two components but I get this error

```
 bundling failed: Error: require() must have a single string literal argument
```

walkThroughtComponent

```
        import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
        View,
        Text,
        Button
    } from 'react-native';

    // styles
    import { style } from './style';
    import { globalStyle } from '../../assets/styles/globalStyle';

    // third library 
    import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

    // import animations
    import LottieAnimation from '../../components/common/LottieAnimation';

    saveWelcome = () =>{
      // save welcome token after see the welcome slider
    }

    const Walkthrough = (props) => {
        const { wrapper, slide1, slide2, slide3, text } = style;  



        return (
                <Swiper style={ wrapper } showsButtons={true} loop = {false}>
                    <View style={ slide1 }>
                        <LottieAnimation name="CheckMark.json"/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ slide2 }>
                    <Text style={ text }>Beautiful</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={ slide3 }>
                    <Text style={ text }>And simple</Text>
                    <Button title="LOG IN" color='red' onPress={() => console.log("save in asyncStorage")} />
                    </View>
                </Swiper>   
            );
    }



    export default Walkthrough;
```

the component I want to pass the props and use there

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Animation from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class LottieAnimation extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.animation.play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animation
        ref={animation => { this.animation = animation; }}
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        }}
        source={require(`./AnimationsJson/${this.props.name}.json`)}
        loop ={ true }
        speed = {0.1}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use the this.props.name variable and to use the path for source require but I really stuck because this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set 'require' directly into the child component. Please check below updated lines,

```
<LottieAnimation name={require("CheckMark.json")} />
<Animation
        ref={animation => { this.animation = animation; }}
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
        }}
        source={this.props.name}
        loop ={ true }
        speed = {0.1}
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

Won't work. You have to "pre-require" all the animations into an object and then make a reference over there:

```
const animations = {
  fizz: require('fizz.json'),
  buzz: require('buzz.json'),
};

...

<Animation
  ...
  source={animations[this.props.name]}
  ...
/>
```

The good thing in this approach is that you can define additional props in that object, e.g.:

```
const animations = {
  fizz: {
    source: 'fizz.json',
    loop: false,
    speed: 0.1,
  },
}
```

Comment: thanks it was the problem! why I can't do it in my way?

Comment: @zvona is there a way to identify all the places `require` is being used dynamically within a component, inside a large code base?